# Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables, setting foreign_keys

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Teams"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    flashscore_id = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    leagues = db.relationship("League",
                    secondary=league_teams_table)

    standings = db.relationship('Standing', backref='teams', cascade="all,delete")
    fixtures = db.relationship('Fixture', backref='teams', cascade="all,delete")

related_fixtures_table = db.Table('RelatedFixtures',
    db.Column('fixture_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Fixtures.id')),
    db.Column('related_fixture_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Fixtures.id')))

class Fixture(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Fixtures"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    home_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Teams.id'),
        nullable=False)
    away_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Teams.id'),
        nullable=False)

    home_ref = db.relationship("Teams", backref="fixture", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[home_id])
    away_ref = db.relationship("Teams", backref="fixture", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[away_id])

    flashscore_id = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    total_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    total_fh_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    total_sh_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

    total_home_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    total_away_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    total_home_fh_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    total_home_sh_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

    total_away_fh_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)
    total_away_sh_goals = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=0)

    related_fixtures = db.relationship("Fixture",
                    secondary=related_fixtures_table)
```

I wrote the above code trying to define multiple relations between Fixture & Team. When I run the application and execute an action I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Team.fixtures - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

I tried solving this by adding the following two lines:

```
home_ref = db.relationship("Teams", backref="fixture", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[home_id])
    away_ref = db.relationship("Teams", backref="fixture", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[away_id])
```

But I still get the same error. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: For my problem (very similar to yours) it worker very well this example from the official documentation: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths.  As soon as I finish my tasks I will try to post my answer to your question, in case you don't find the answer in the example of the link.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get rid of `fixtures = db.relationship('Fixture', backref='teams', cascade="all,delete")` in `Team`.

What you will have at the end is:

```
class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Teams"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    
    # ...
    

class Fixture(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Fixtures"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    home_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Teams.id'), nullable=False)
    away_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Teams.id'), nullable=False)

    home_ref = db.relationship("Teams", backref="fixture", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[home_id])
    away_ref = db.relationship("Teams", backref="fixture", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[away_id])
    
    # ...
```

You have your foreign keys defined in `home_id` and `away_id`, then you specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table. Refer to this section in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#handling-multiple-join-paths).

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the `fixtures` relationship on the `Team` class, because that's what the error is telling you to do: `Could not determine join condition ... on relationship Team.fixtures`.

However, you can't fix this situation with `foreign_keys`; that expects a *single* (possibly compound) foreign key, and you have *two, distinct* foreign key relationships. You'd have to create two separate relationships, one for fixtures where this team is the home team, and another one for the `away` relationship.

If you want `Team.fixtures` to return a list of all `Fixture` rows that reference the team via one or both foreign keys, you need to create a custom `primaryjoin` condition, one that matches your `Team.id` against the `home_id` *or* the `away_id` column (and you probably want to add a `DISTINCT` condition to your query to avoid getting duplicate results for fixtures that connect to your team via both foreign keys).